# Errors in .csv characters

Tags: r, memory, character, limit

I have problem working with .csv files in Rstudio. I am gettig this error, how solve it? The error is below:

> Error in as.character.default(x) :    R character strings are limited
> to 2^31-1 bytes

Comment: R does not yet enjoy 64-bit vector lengths in much of what it does. This is slowly change (I don't have a timeline). Often, exceeding that is one of: (1) a mistake, perhaps a mistaken cartesian join/expansion of things; (2) a mistake, a file is misread/mis-parsed and things go squirrelly; or (3) something that should really be done in a database or a distribute "Big Data"-like environment (though many non-big DBMSes can handle 2^31 without going "Gig"). What were you doing when you got this error?

Comment: I am working with CSV files and trying to remove duplicates, clean data .etc. I can't post all function because too long characters. Can I post code in github and from that to read code.

Comment: When I have this error can I increase memory in Rstudio. I have tried memory.limit(), memory.size() and these functions not works well. The memory size was not increased. Like memory.size(x), where x - memory size.

Comment: It is generally preferred to have questions be self-contained within the SO environment. While external links (e.g., to a github repo) can provide good context, for some it is a fast deterrent. Feel free to add a link to the repo, maybe somebody will have the time to pour through your code. However, you may find that some will take issue with the fact that you're not able to reduce your code to a manageable scale before asking a question ... turning your question into a form of code *audit*, even if that's not what you had in mind. Good luck.